# querying binary column using like in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008. In my table I have a column called `TestData` of type `binary`.

Sample data in TestData column are

```
1. 0x0001DC780C0030373156635D0C00B8840301009A0600AC
2. 0x0301DC780C0030373156385D0C006499C401009A0600AC
```

Wrote below two queries to get the rows where TestData starts with "0x0001". But none of them are working.

```
SELECT * 
FROM T_TRANSACTION 
WHERE  CAST(Indicium AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '0x0001%'

----No results found

SELECT * 
FROM T_TRANSACTION 
WHERE  CAST(Indicium AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '0x0001%'

----Returns all the rows
```

Please correct the query to get the expected results

Comment: Your two queries are exactly the same? Also I added an answer with more explanation and code to do a two-sided wildcard LIKE.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Don't convert it, but treat is as a range (like you would datetime values)

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (TestData varbinary(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT @foo (TestData) VALUES
         (0x0001DC780C0030373156635D0C00B8840301009A0600AC),
         (0x0001AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA),
         (0x0001AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF),
         (0x0301DC780C0030373156385D0C006499C401009A0600AC),
         (0x0301FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF),
         (0x0302000000000000000000000000000000000000000000);

SELECT *
FROM @foo
WHERE TestData >= 0x0001 AND TestData < 0x0002;

-- added more digit for clarity of what actually happens
SELECT *
FROM @foo
WHERE TestData >= 0x00010000 AND TestData < 0x00020000;

SELECT *
FROM @foo
WHERE TestData >= 0x0001AA AND TestData < 0x0001AB;

SELECT *
FROM @foo
WHERE TestData >= 0x0301 AND TestData < 0x0302;
```

This has the bonus of being able to use an index on TestData

Edit, you just specify as many digits as you need

Comment: What do i have to do when i want to search **`'0x0301%'`**

Comment: +1 This is obviously the best way to do searches on `BINARY` fields of fixed length.

Comment: AWESOME!!! This gives me like a 1000x perf improvement. The cast(... as varchar(max)) answer below does not use my index; this answer is the way to go. "where a.hierarchy between b.hierarchy and b.hierarchy+0xFF", for example.

Answer (score 3):

For a leading prefix LIKE comparison, gbn's answer will do.  For a **real** LIKE equivalence of string searches, you can use LIKE as follows:
*(borrowing schema and sample data from @gbn)*

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE (TestData varbinary(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT @foo (TestData) VALUES
         (0x0001DC780C0030373156635D0C00B8),
         (0x0001AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA),
         (0x0001AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF),
         (0x0301DC780C0030373156385D0C006499C401009A0600AC),
         (0x0301FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF),
         (0x0302000000000000000000000000000000000000000000);

SELECT *
FROM @foo
WHERE CAST(TestData AS VARCHAR(MAX)) LIKE '%'+CAST(0xDC78 AS VARCHAR(MAX))+'%';
```

When you cast a binary value to VARCHAR, all it does is treat the raw bits as a string stream. It does not magically convert it into the string representation.  Consider the example below:

```
select cast(0x41 as varchar(10));     -- Result: A
select cast(0x414263 as varchar(10)); -- Result: ABc
```

Because the byte 0x41 or ordinal 65 is 'A' in the standard Latin codepage.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the byte array as string, use it like a number.

all you need to do is:

> SELECT *  FROM T_TRANSACTION  WHERE  Indicium >= 0x0001

or if you want to get a scpecific one:

> SELECT *  FROM T_TRANSACTION  WHERE  Indicium >=0x0001DC780C0030373156635D0C00B8840301009A0600AC