# Argument type varchar invalid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL code that I am running and am getting an error when I pass in certain information.

```
select * from OBX.BTOCUST
--where [CUSTID] like 'sci'
--order by BRANDING desc
where BRANDING not like '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
```

When I uncomment the `--where [CUSTID] like 'sci'` and comment out branding the query runs and am able to see results. But when I run where branding I get an error:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 2 of like function.

also another thing is when i uncomment the order by BRANDING desc it gives me another error.

that error is

> Msg 306, Level 16, State 2, Line 3 The text, ntext, and image data
>   types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE
>   operator.

What do I need to do to get the command to actually work?

Comment: Why not just use `<>`?  What is the data type of `BRANDING`?

Comment: What is a the datatype of branding??

Comment: My guess would be that `BRANDING` is a binary type, if you *really* want a `LIKE` comparison, then test for the value being in a range, as [described in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16188496/1048425), otherwise just use `<>`  as Gordon has suggested. If you are using binary types, then you don't need to use literals, it should just be `0x47...` not `'0x47...'`

Comment: branding is an image

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @JeroenMostert change you comment to an answer. It worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message is what you get if `BRANDING` is of type `IMAGE`, which is incomparable (as in, literally, it cannot be compared in any way, not even to another `IMAGE`). To overcome the limitations of this type, SQL Server 2005 introduced the `VARBINARY(MAX)` type, which has the same purpose but isn't burdened with the special case handling that `IMAGE` requires (likewise, `(N)VARCHAR(MAX)` was introduced to replace `(N)TEXT`). `IMAGE` should not be used for new work; `VARBINARY(MAX)` is superior in all respects. If existing `IMAGE` columns can be changed to `VARBINARY(MAX)`, do so.

If that isn't possible, the `IMAGE` can still be converted on the fly. In the query above:

```
select * from OBX.BTOCUST
where CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), BRANDING) <> 0x476737.....00003B
```

Here the `0x476737....` is a `BINARY` literal. To convert a hexstring to a binary, use `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @string, 1)` (with leading "0x") or `CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), @string, 2)` (without leading "0x").

Answer (score 0):

Convert your image or text or ntext column data type to varbinary(max), varchar(max) or nvarchar(max).

The image, text, and ntext data types are deprecated and will be removed in a future version of SQL Server.  They are very difficult and awkward to work with.  The varchar(max) and nvarchar(max) have all the benefits of nearly unlimited string size, and none of the drawbacks of text or ntext.  They also work with all the normal string functions you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty way of doing it that I just put together, but keep in mind what you are asking of your server in the absence of fulltext.  It ignores the data type mismatches as low level errors in your message output.  You can check the message output for a rudimentary sort of progress on it as it is running.

```
Declare @SearchString nvarchar(50) = 'SEARCH STRING HERE'
Declare @TableList Table (TableName nvarchar(128))
Declare @Table nvarchar(128)
Declare @ColumnList Table (ColumnName nvarchar(128))
Declare @Column nvarchar(128)
Declare @Results Table (TableName nvarchar(128), ColumnName nvarchar(128), String nvarchar(max))
Declare @cmd nvarchar(max)

Insert Into @TableList
Select TABLE_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Tables Where Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'

While Exists (Select 1 From @TableList)
Begin

Set @Table = (Select Top 1 TableName From @TableList)
Print 'Searching '+@Table+'...'

Insert Into @ColumnList
Select Column_Name From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.Columns Where Table_Name = @Table

While Exists (Select 1 From @ColumnList)
Begin

    Set @Column = (Select Top 1 ColumnName From @ColumnList)
    Print 'Searching ' +@Table + '.' + @Column+'...'

    Set @cmd = 'Select '''+@Table+''', '''+@Column+''', '+@Column+' From '+@Table+' Where '+@Column+' Like ''%'+@SearchString+'%'''     

    --Select @cmd

    Insert Into @Results
    Exec (@cmd)

    Delete From @ColumnList Where ColumnName = @Column

End

Delete From @TableList Where TableName = @Table

End

Select * From @Results
```